# Pairing Based Crypto Library Initializing element_t objects

Tags: c++

I am doing my first steps with the PBC library(http://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/manual/) and I have a very basic problem.

I have a vector

```
std::vector<element_t> h;
```

and i'm trying to fill it with element_t objects, which are the basic building blocks for pretty much anything in this library. 
I do this in a loop as follows

```
element_t z[size];
// Pick random z_i and initialize h = g^z_i
for(int i = 0; i<size; i++)
{   
    element_init_Zr(z[i], pairing);
    element_random(z[i]);
    element_printf("created random z[%i] = %B\n", i, z[i]);

    element_t tmp;
    element_init_G1(tmp, pairing);

    element_pow_zn(tmp, g, z[i]);
    element_printf("tmp is %B\n", tmp);
    h.push_back(tmp);
}
```

This attempt results in an pretty long error message, which I dont really understand, but I think it means something like element_t is not actually element_t so don't fill the vector with that...

If I change the vector into a vector that takes element_t *, then it compiles, but at the end all pointer point to the same element for some reason(to the last one pushed into the vector).

When I try something like element_t tmp = new element_t(); then I get

```
error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
```

I dont really understand what i'm doing wrong (also i'm pretty new to c++ in general) so I would appreciate any helpful advice. 
How can I correctly initialize the vector with element_t objects in it?

Comment: I think the problem is that PBC is a C library and `element_t` is missing the required copy constructor for `vector` to work with it. Note that there is a C++ wrapper for PBC available: http://crysp.uwaterloo.ca/software/PBCWrapper/